# I am having trouble using constraints to make my screen (labels, text) to expand when the screen expands

Tags: xcode, storyboard, constraints

For multiple weeks I have been trying to solve this problem which I believe (or hope) has an easy solution.  The goal is for my schedule (in the picture) to expand to the exact size of the screen and adapt if someone uses an iPhone or iPad.

[image: picture]

Comment: use collectionView/stackview but you may encounter trimming labels for small devices

Comment: I would also agree with @Sh_Khan, using a collection view here would be appropriate; set the constraints for it to be filled the screen, also make sure to let the item sizes to be promotional based on the screen size.

Comment: Thank you for this help.  I'm a little confused on using these containers.  Do I  put each thing (label, text whatever) in a separate cell or how does this work?  Sorry